# Right way to publish custom classes from Laravel Package

Tags: laravel, laravel-package, laravel-config

Lets say I'm building a laravel package, which has hierarchy like this:

`PackageContainerClass > *PackageClass* > SomePackageClassMethod()`

I want to make `PackageClass` swappable by a class from main `App`.

I know I could create a publishable `config/package_config.php` where the user could override `PackageClass` location and then use it for creating `PackageClass` object in the package. But I have quite a few classes to be 'swapped', and dont really feel that its the right approach. What's the best approach for this, is there any Laravel magic I dont know about?

Comment: You could use a service provider class to bind the swappable classes to a singleton. `app()->singleton(PackageInterface::class, PackageClass::class)`. I recommend checking the source code for  `laravel/fortify` as it uses this approach quite a lot.

Comment: This sounds like a much better approach, will explore. Thanks!